# react native horizontal flatlist getting crashed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using react native flatlist to render some data inside react native flatlist where I want to flatlist to be horizontal. for the data that is to renderitem I have created a seperate function and called that inside my flatlist. I have some images and text inside my renderitem, now the problem is when I render only text it seems to work fine, but when I add images it is crashing.
Below is my renderitem:

```
renderOtherBannerItem =(childItem, index)=>(
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={this.onClickListenerForImageCategoryBrandProductBanner.bind(this, childItem)}
    style={{
        width: childItem.width,
        height: childItem.height,
        padding: 3,
    }}>
    {childItem.numColumns == 1 ? (
       <Image
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            shadowColor: "#000",
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 1,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.18,
            shadowRadius: 1.0,
            elevation: 1,
            width: "100%",
            borderRadius: 4,
            height: childItem.height,
            resizeMode: "stretch",
          }}
          source={{ uri: childItem.img }}
        />)
```

and I have called it inside :

```
<FlatList
  style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
  numColumns={numColumns}
  data={bannerViewList}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderOtherBannerItem(item, index)}
/>;
```

Could anyone please tell what wrong am I doing inside the render function, any leads would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ? is it an overflow error?

Comment: unhandled promise rejection

Comment: the image is a network image ?

Comment: check your `{childItem.numColumns == 1 ?`, the ternary is not completed, it should be `{childItem.numColumns == 1 ? (<Image/>) : (<Another JSX/>)` even thought you don't need to handle `conditional rending` inside `renderItem` instead `{childItem.numColumns == 1 ? <YourJSXFor1Column/> : <Flatlist renderItem={<YourJSXForMoreColumn}`